# How to install Sqlite3 on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, sqlite

I am having a hell of a time getting SQLite3 installed. I have gotten all the latest stuff in terms of Ruby and Rails, the gems, etc. Everything says "Nothing to update". But when I try to install the DB I have the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while... 
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
extconf.rb mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 38):

Did you have SQLite3 installed in system?

If you're using MacPorts:

```
sudo port install sqlite3
```

or Brew:

```
brew install sqlite3
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a RoR newbie. Here's what I did: unknowne4ce8f5514cd:~ mgrimmett76$ sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby

Comment: But first you need to install SQLite3 in your system using MacPorts or Brew package managers.

Answer (score 4):

In order to install `sqlite3` on Mac using `brew`, you can simply run:

```
$ brew install sqlite3
```

Probably, you have already installed `sqlite3` because by default it comes installed since [Mac OSX 10.4 onwards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite). In this case, you can update `sqlite3` using `brew` by running the following command:

```
$ brew upgrade sqlite3
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a version of MacOS with `sqlite3` preinstalled, i.e. any modern version, then as other answers point out you can install/upgrade to the latest version using Homebrew:

```
brew install sqlite3

- or -

brew upgrade sqlite3
```

But, if you then run `sqlite3` you'll see it's **still using the preinstalled version** by default.

To use the version installed by Homebrew, you need to update your PATH to point to it, by adding the following to `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin:$PATH"
```

Running `sqlite3` should now show the latest version running.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have XCode 4 installed, but version 3 instead. After installing 4 I am good to go.